# Create and Excel Document using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, save

Hi I am new to Python and am currently working through the book Automate the boring stuff with Python. I am trying to scrape a website that requires a login. The below code does work to a point and saves the required information in 'pricingtable'. I need to get this into an Excel or .txt file is there a way to do this using selenium?

Being new and not fulling understanding is there a better way to do this with requests and bs4? It seems silly to open a browser to do this but i don't know another way.

Thank you in advance.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import openpyxl, requests, bs4
import time

# opens website in Firefox
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://somewebsite/somepage)

# find a username element and passes the password
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('Enter user name')
emailElem.send_keys('*username*')

# finds the password element and passes the password
passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_name('passwd')
passwordElem.send_keys('*password*')
passwordElem.submit()

#allows the browser to open but may not be required
time.sleep(2)

# selects a new webpage 
browser.get('https://somewebsite/pricing')

# on the new webpage there is an element table 
pricetable = browser.find_element_by_id('Pricetable')
```

Comment: How many columns?

Comment: I'm not sure I believe the table has 6 columns

Answer (score 0):

You can save the table easily in a CSV, 
CSV files are file formats that contain plain text values separated by commas. CSV files can be opened by any spreadsheet program: Microsoft Excel, Open Office, Google Sheets, etc.

```
import csv

#....
pricetable = browser.find_element_by_id('Pricetable')
with open('pricetable.csv', 'a') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    for row in pricetable.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
        wr.writerow([d.text for d in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')])
```

Comment: thanks @too Tired but I get the error : AttributeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object has no attribute 'to_csv'